# How to write a many-to-many relationship in Fluent in MVC4 and Entity Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to write a many-to-many relationship in the override of the onModelCreating method of my context in ASP.NET MVC4.  I think I have my classes wrong because I'm getting errors in Intellisense that I don't understand.  Here is my override:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Software>().
          HasMany(i => i.LocationId).
          WithMany(c => c.SoftwareId).
          Map(mc =>
          {
               mc.MapLeftKey("SoftwareId");
               mc.MapRightKey("LocationId");
               mc.ToTable("SoftwareLocations");
          });

 }
```

Here is my Software class:

```
public class Software
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<SoftwareType> SoftwareTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public virtual List<SoftwarePublisher> Publishers { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Platform { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        public bool Suite { get; set; }
        public string SubscriptionEndDate { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(3)]
        public int SeatCount { get; set; }
        public virtual Location LocationId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Location class:

```
public class Location
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public virtual Software SoftwareId { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I write my Fluent override so I can map them correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many-to-Many means that in both entities is Collections. So you should set HasMany(software=>software.Locations) and set WithMany(location=>location.Softwares) as in example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Software>().
          HasMany(i => i.Locations).
          WithMany(c => c.Softwares).
          Map(mc =>
          {
               mc.MapLeftKey("SoftwareId");
               mc.MapRightKey("LocationId");
               mc.ToTable("SoftwareLocations");
          });

 }
```

Here is my Software class:

```
public class Software
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SoftwareType> SoftwareTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection <Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SoftwarePublisher> Publishers { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public bool Suite { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionEndDate { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    //[StringLength(3)]
    public int SeatCount { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Location class:

```
 public class Location
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [StringLength(20)]
            public string LocationName { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
        }
```